How can I reduce memory using in Openliberty
When I start a war application with oepnliberty, it uses too many memory. The heap is also very large. When I start several web application, it cost more than 12G.
Is there a way to reduce the memory by using some params in server.xml or someWhere else. Thanks for your answer!

It is not fault of the OpenLiberty but your app. You need to see why your app takes soo much memory and redesign it.

Depending on the Java version, and the amount of memory, Java will reserve a percentage of memory on startup by default, it is also possible that your application server has been configured to reserve 12 GiB. Without more information, this is impossible to diagnose.

It about 40 war application start up together. By Jprofile analyze, I found metadata use about 5G memory, but there is no way to release it.

Are these SpringBoot applications?  If not, it would be good to consider moving common libraries in the application to shared libraries instead of having those duplicated in each application.

They are SpringBoot applications, I have use common library to reduce the memory consumption

Not specifically to reduce the memory your application uses, but you can utilize the jvm.options file, as detailed in https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/performance-tuning.html, to set a maximum heap size for your application server (i.e. -Xmx512m).

I set the Xmx 12G, because there are about 40 war application start up together. I want to reduce the memory consumption as much as possible while ensuring startup speed.
